# Tryin to use wp_localize_script for ajax call, but callback is not running

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and I'm trying to run an ajax call to get content from the database after a form submission. So far I am trying to put the wp_localize_scripts together, but it isn't echoing out anything. Am I calling my function correctly?

```
wp_register_script( 'form-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/library/js/formHandle.js', array(), '', true);
        wp_localize_script( 'form-handle', 'ajaxUrl', 
admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_publication', 'search_publications');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_publication', 'search_publications');

function search_publications(){
            echo 'hello'

            wp_die();
        };
```

And then when I go to the URL http://testsite.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=publication, nothing is showing up except for a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came on this thread by accident but I decided to answer even if it is too late. I hope it gonna help someone ^^

There are some errors in what you showed us.
Is that parts of code ?

First of all, you should always use hooks. Use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) hook to register scripts & localize script.
That gives you :

```
function my_enqueue_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'form-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/formHandle.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_localize_script( 'form-handle', 'jsData',[
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ]);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'my_enqueue_script');
```

As you can see I also fixed the wrong usage of [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). In the documentation of this function, you can see 2nd parameter define the name of the JS var and **3rd parameter must be an array**.
With this code, you can access your ajax url with : `jsData.ajaxUrl`

Finally, I would like to mention that you can reach URL http://testsite.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=publication but I would suggest to use POST method and nonce verification instead.

If you see "0" that means that Wordpress cant reach the action. Make sure the file(s) where the functions are defined is loaded. You can also try to call the function manually with another hook.